# Why am I getting white lines in my tiled map when my character moves?

Tags: rendering, tiles

I followed the tutorial here -

http://mainroach.blogspot.com/2013/02/fast-html5-canvas-rendering-tiled-maps.html

I can't really figure out why it's happening. At certain times the map looks fine and then when I move my character the map starts to look like this - [image]

Comment: Your tiles seem to be trying to fit a bit too perfectly. Usually, game algorithms will pick speed over precision, so you might need a bit of a leeway in your tiles (maybe make them one pixel bigger than what they're supposed to fit into).

Comment: Could also be a int vs float problem. How are the tiles position determined?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is a white tile above or below the offending tile in your tilemap. When it renders that tile a bit of the adjacent white tile it bleeds onto the other tile. Changing the blending mode to nearest neighbor should fix the problem.